# In Keychain Access on OS X, Find matching public and private keys

Tags: keychain, public-key, keychain-access

I have a couple keys that seem to have been generated with the same names. I would like to know which public key match up with which private keys so I can rename/delete them. Is this something that is important (keeping around the public key) or does a public key get generated each time you request a certificate?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?  I have the same problem and can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: No, I haven't. The best solution I have found is to just give them more unique name to begin with unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, that's not terribly helpful AFTER we've already made the mistake of not naming them properly.  ;)  I've seen rumblings that suggest the OpenSSL command line tool may be able to help, but I haven't yet figured out how.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess you have been able to get around your problem as this is an old thread, but I am just writing a reply for any future reference.

The basic idea is to export your private and public keys, and use openssl to view their modulus. Matching private/public keys will have the same modulus.

Here is how to see the modulus of a private key:

1. In Keychain Access export your private key and select "Personal Information Exchange (.p12)" file format. This will create .p12 file.
2. Launch a terminal and use openssl to convert your .p12 file to a .pem file:

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -out key.pem -nodes
   ```
3. Use openssl to view the modulus of the pem private key:

   ```
   openssl rsa -in key.pem -modulus -noout
   ```

Here is how to see the modulus of a public key:

1. In Keychain Access export your public key and select "Privacy Enhanced Mail (.pem)" file format. This will create .pem file.
2. This .pem file is a PKCS#1 PEM file (with a header `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`), while openssl can only read PKCS#8 PEM (with a header `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`). So open up your exported public key in TextEdit and remove the `RSA` bit from the header and the footer, and save the changes.
3. Use openssl to view the modulus of the pem public key:

   ```
   openssl rsa -pubin -in pubkey.pem -modulus -noout
   ```

Please also note that in fact, you could also delete your public keys and re-create them from the private keys (that way you could be certain of your matching pairs). To create the matching public key from a private key use the following openssl command:

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout -out pubkey.pem
```

Comment: Thanks, old question but seeming always a problem so it's nice to finally have a good solution.

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for. Thanks for the good description.

Comment: I just about asked this question again on SuperUser, but have been so fortunate to discover this answer already given.. +1 all around.

Comment: To see the modulus of a public certificate: `openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in public.[crt|pem]`